# dSPACE AutomationDesk Export report as pdf using python

Tags: python, pdf, export, report, dspace-ecu

I am executing test set using dSPACE AumationDesk 5.4. I could successfully execute the `adp` file.
And generated the report in the input adp file path.

I need to export the result as a pdf file with a custom folder.
Used the below method to export the same.

```
ProjObject.Export('../report.pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

[In the File Menu Select Options

[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzvu1.png)

[Under the Report in Options change the Report generation to PDF

[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZecQo.png)